# Password Protected Directory Link Shows Maintenance Mode Page

Tags: plugins, password

In my WordPress installed directory, I have placed a directory named "Projects". My WordPress site is in maintenance mode with Maintenance Mode Plugin Installed on it. I password protected  my "Projects" directory from cPanel, but instead of asking username & password it shows maintenance mode page. Any idea ?

Comment: Does that plugin edit your `.htaccess` file?

Comment: Plugin is not editing .htaccess file created by cPanel in "Projects" directory.

Answer (score 0):

There's likely a .maintenance file in the directory, if you FTP in you should be able to remove it.

http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Site_Maintenance

Comment: Hi, Christopher, your Answer is showing up in the *Low Quality* review process. A bit more of context is always welcome, as well as links to the documentation.

Comment: No, there is not any .maintenance file.